# Notification to open an app in chrome using selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I was trying to send a message to customers of a shop through whatsapp using the "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+*number* " but as I do this I get a pop up asking to open the whatsapp application. As I am doing this with selenium (python) I tried to use the driver. switch_to_alert().accept()
But it says no such alert please do help **strong text**

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it isn't an alert window and it is actually a pop-up window. For this you need to switch the driver window:

```py
#Switch to new window
self.driver.switch_to.window(self.driver.window_handles[1])
#Do stuff....

#Switch to old window
self.driver.switch_to.window(self.driver.window_handles[0])
```

I believe you can also use:

```
self.driver.switch_to_default_content()
```

If you've switched to a child frame, to switch back to the original window.